# Football teams qualifed for World Cup with no loss

Tags: football, trivia, history, world-cup, qualifying

With only one more match to play, the Iranian National team has already qualified for Russia 2018 World Cup without losing a game in any rounds of the qualifiers. How many teams which played in the qualifying rounds have made it to the World Cup without a single loss since the tournament expanded to 24 teams (that is since 1982 WC at Spain)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [1982](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1982_FIFA_World_Cup_qualification)

- **West Germany (8-0-0)**
- Soviet Union (6-2-0)
- **Poland (4-0-0)**
- **Brazil (4-0-0)**
- Peru (2-2-0)
- Chile (3-1-0)
- Honduras (3-2-0)

### [1986](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1986_FIFA_World_Cup_qualification)

- England (4-4-0)
- Brazil (2-2-0)
- Canada (5-3-0)
- Algeria (5-1-0)

### [1990](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1990_FIFA_World_Cup_qualification)

- Sweden (4-2-0)
- England (3-3-0)
- Netherlands (4-2-0)
- West Germany (3-3-0)
- Yugoslavia (6-2-0)
- Belgium (4-4-0)
- Brazil (3-1-0)
- South Korea (9-2-0)

### [1994](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_FIFA_World_Cup_qualification)

- Greece (6-2-0)
- Colombia (4-2-0)
- Saudi Arabia (6-5-0)

### [1998](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1998_FIFA_World_Cup_qualification)

- Italy (6-4-0)
- Norway (6-2-0)
- Spain (8-2-0)
- Romania (9-1-0)
- Germany (6-4-0)
- Tunisia (7-1-0)
- Morocco (5-1-0)
- Cameroon (4-2-0)

*Side note: after CONMEBOL introduced the round-robin qualification format for World Cup 1998, no team from this confederation was able to qualify without a loss.*

### [2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_FIFA_World_Cup_qualification)

- Portugal (7-3-0)
- Denmark (6-4-0)
- Sweden (8-2-0)
- Croatia (5-3-0)
- Spain (6-2-0)
- Italy (6-2-0)
- Slovenia (6-6-0)
- Tunisia (8-2-0)
- South Africa (7-1-0)

### [2006](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_FIFA_World_Cup_qualification)

- Netherlands (10-2-0)
- Portugal (9-3-0)
- France (5-5-0)
- Serbia and Montenegro (6-4-0)
- Croatia (7-3-0)
- Spain (6-6-0)
- Saudi Arabia (10-2-0)

### [2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_FIFA_World_Cup_qualification)

- Germany (8-2-0)
- **Spain (10-0-0)**
- Italy (7-3-0)
- **Netherlands (8-0-0)**
- Nigeria (9-3-0)
- Ivory Coast (8-4-0)
- South Korea (7-7-0)

### [2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_FIFA_World_Cup_qualification)

- Belgium (8-2-0)
- Italy (6-4-0)
- Germany (9-1-0)
- Netherlands (9-1-0)
- Switzerland (7-3-0)
- England (6-4-0)
- Spain (6-2-0)
- Nigeria (5-3-0)
- Ivory Coast (5-3-0)

### [2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup_qualification)

- Iran (12-6-0)
- **Germany (10-0-0)**
- Spain (9-1-0)
- Belgium (9-1-0)
- England (8-2-0)
- Tunisia (6-2-0)
- Nigeria (5-3-0)
- Senegal (5-3-0)

*Note: **bold** indicates the teams winning all the qualification matches.*